# How to write record in a new line.(on the output.dat ile)

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I am trying to output the the current console display to the TFileOut.da file. But when I try to write a record, all the data gets outputted into the same line.

```
       PROGRAM-ID. TFile.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
        SELECT myInFile ASSIGN TO "TestFile.dat".
        SELECT myOutFile ASSIGN TO "TFileOut.dat".
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD myInFile.
       01 inRecord.
        02 StudentName    PIC X(15).
        02 StudentWNbr    PIC X(8).
        02 Years          PIC X(9).
        02 Course         PIC X(9).
        02 CourseD        PIC X(28).
        02 Grade          PIC X(1).
        02 CreditHr       PIC 9.
        02 FILLER         PIC X(1).
       FD myOutFile.
       01 studentOutRecord.
        02 DatFile PIC X(10).
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 w PIC X(3) VALUE "YES".
       01 stor PIC X(9).
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
        OPEN INPUT myInFile.
        OPEN OUTPUT myOutFile.
        PERFORM subRead
        PERFORM UNTIL w = "NO" 
        PERFORM subRead
        END-PERFORM.
        CLOSE myInFile.
        CLOSE myOutFile.
        STOP RUN.
       subRead.
        READ myInFile
        AT END
        MOVE "NO" TO w
        NOT AT END
        DISPLAY Course
        MOVE Course TO 
        MOVE Course to DatFile
        WRITE studentOutRecord
        END-READ.
```

The is the output in the output file.
CMPS 161  MATH 223  MATH 200  HIST 101  MATH 223  MATH 200  HIST 101  PHYS 101  MUSC 101  PSYC 101  SSYC 101

```
This is how I get into console.
CMPS 161 
MATH 223 
MATH 200 
HIST 101 
MATH 223 
MATH 200 
HIST 101 
PHYS 101 
MUSC 101 
PSYC 101 
SSYC 101
```

I want to display the output file same as the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In FILE-CONTROL set the organization to line sequential.

```
        SELECT myInFile ASSIGN  TO "TestFile.dat"
               organization is line sequential.

        SELECT myOutFile ASSIGN TO "TFileOut.dat"
               organization is line sequential.
```

This will keep the line feeds intact.
I run GNUCobol under Linux and without using line sequential everything packs into one line.

Comment: > and without using line sequential everything packs into one line
That's the absolute correct thing to do because in this case you request a fixed-length file without additional line delimiter.
A `SEQUENTIAL` file can include any data, including computational and binary which may seems like a line-delimiter (or null) which can create different problems in `LINE SEQUENTIAL` files.